# open which option to erase the file if it exists in C

Tags: c

I am new with `open` function in C. For now to open a file named file I am doing the following :

```
open("file",  O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)
```

If the file doesn't exist it does create the file and it gives the right to read the file and to write at the end of it.

Yet the problem is that if the file already exists it doesn't erase its content. What is the option I should use here ?

Comment: You're asking to `O_APPEND`, which means "please add to the end of the file if it exists", so maybe you don't want that?

Answer (score 0):

`O_APPEND` means you'll be appending to the file if it exists. You should use `O_TRUNC` instead:

```c
open("file",  O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)
/* Here ---------------------^ */
```

Comment: Oooooh that's why when I tried O_TRUNC it didn't work, it's because of the O_APPEND. Thank you btw

Comment: For future reference, O_APPEND, O_TRUNC, and O_EXCL are all mutually exclusive.